# Internet Explorer and jQuery issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a script that works in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome. It just doesn't work in Internet Explorer for whatever reason. The code is fairly simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.tabSwap = function() {

        return this.each(function() {
            $('.current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
        });

    };

})( jQuery );
</script>
```

On [a fairly simplified page](http://jsbin.com/ulaho#noedit) (posted by Roatin Marth) the code worked just fine in IE 6 and IE 8. On [my webpage](http://examples.chikachu.com/calculators) the code does not work at all in Internet Explorer.

I tried executing the following simple code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#statistics').tabSwap();
</script>
```

I get the following error:

> > **Object doesn't support this property or method**
> >
> > index.html line: 77
> >
> > code: 0 char: 2
> >
> > URI: ...

The link to my webpage is:

http://examples.chikachu.com/calculators

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Works fine: http://jsbin.com/ulaho#noedit (tested in IE6). What are you seeing?

Comment: @Roatin Huh... the link you sent me worked in IE8. There must be something further with my site that's complicating it. I'll upload my website, re-test, and post a link if it still doesn't work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Comment: @Crescent That fixed the problem, thank you =) Please post as an answer so I can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was posted by [Crescent Fresh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45433/crescent-fresh), but he isn't posting it as an answer so I can accept it. The problem on my site was improper closing of the `<script>` tag used to include the jQuery framework.

More specifically, [this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 0):

As a replacement for the JS you listed at the top, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.fn.tabSwap = function() {

        return this.each(function() {
            $('.current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
        });

};    

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tabTwo').tabSwap();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't declare plugins inside a `document.ready` handler.

Comment: When I tried this, nothing happened. No errors, but the tab never swapped (in IE).

Comment: @steven_desu I updated the answer.. I was able to make this work at your example website using the chrome console.

Comment: Problem: It worked in Chrome. It didn't work in IE. Crescent Fresh found the issue. I'm just waiting for him to post in answer form so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin is not instantiated when you call it in IE -- try wrapping the call for your plugin in `$()` to make sure the DOM is ready (which theoretically should mean that your plugin has been downloaded and parsed [and therefore registered with jQuery.])

So change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#tabTwo').tabSwap();
</script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() { 
        $('#tabTwo').tabSwap(); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This method threw the same error as before, only it threw the error twice.